# Accessing private variable from another class in Java

Tags: java

I am using my main method from class Test and am trying to call a function in an object, Course.  This is the code from my main method:

```
if (decideStatus > .75) {
                status = Classification.GRAD;
                gradCount++;
                if (gpa > 3.2) {
                    Student newStudent = new Student(sID, status, gpa);
                    **addStudentToRoster(newStudent);**
                } else {
                    gradRejectCount++;
                }
```

I am trying to use the addStudentToRoster function to add newStudent to the private variable

```
public class Course {
    private int number = 0;
    private String title = "";
    private int capacity = 0;
    //won't compile with float type for cutoff
    private float cutoff = 0;
    private ArrayList<Student> roster = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<Student> waitlist = new ArrayList<>();

    public Course(int number, String name, int maxSize, float cutoff) {
        //set value of private fields
        this.number = number;
        this.title = name;
        this.capacity = maxSize;
        this.cutoff = cutoff;
    }

    public void addStudentToRoster(Student student) {
        roster.add(student);
    }
```

The addStudentToRoster(newStudent) line has an error stating that that method is undefined for that class.  Does anyone know how I would fix this?

Comment: You need an instance of `Course` in order to call it's `addStudentToRoster` method

Comment: why did I get down voted?

Comment: @user3586248 I dunno. Seems like a clear question to me.

Comment: @user3586248 Your title doesn't relate to the question though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since "addStudentToRoster" is defined inside the Course class, you need to create an instance of that class and modify the problem line of code to be something like:

```
Course comp101 = new Course(1, "comp101", 80, 2.0);
comp101.addStudentToRoster(newStudent);
```